# Update UI from a java class with asyncronous methods

Tags: java, android, multithreading, user-interface, asynchronous

I'm writing a library that manages the connection between Android and a BLE device.
The connection is not synchronous.
I want to update a label in my activity only when the connection state change from disconnected to connected, but I want to keep the library separated from my UI, so I don't want to get in my class the label reference for updating it.

Comment: Have a look to [the guide for background tasks](https://developer.android.com/training/best-background)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use local broadcasts or you can use any event library like https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Post some code if you need more help

Comment: How do I set text of a label in my activity when a boolean variable in a java class change from false to true ?

Comment: post an event using eventBus that value has been changed, now receive that event in your activity and change the text of label there